# How to Make Only First Section Clickable Until All Videos Are Completed

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm working on a web application where I have multiple sections, each containing several lessons. Initially, I want to display all sections to the user, but only make the lessons in the first section clickable and accessible. After a user completes all videos in the first section, I'd like to enable the next section for access. How can I achieve this dynamic behavior using HTML, PHP, and JavaScript? Are there any specific code examples or libraries I can use to implement this feature?

```
<div class="tab-content" id="lessonTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="section_and_lessons" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="section_and_lessons-tab">
        <!-- Lesson Content starts from here -->
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <?php
            foreach ($sections as $key => $section):
                $lessons = $this->crud_model->get_lessons('section', $section['id'])->result_array();?>
                <div class="card" style="margin:0px 0px;">
                    <div class="card-header course_card" id="<?php echo 'heading-'.$section['id']; ?>">

                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="<?php echo '#collapse-'.$section['id']; ?>" <?php if($opened_section_id == $section['id']): ?> aria-expanded="true" <?php else: ?> aria-expanded="false" <?php endif; ?> aria-controls="<?php echo 'collapse-'.$section['id']; ?>" style="color: #535a66; background: none; border: none; white-space: normal;" onclick = "toggleAccordionIcon(this, '<?php echo $section['id']; ?>')">
                                <h6 style="color: #959aa2; font-size: 13px;">
                                    <?php echo get_phrase('section').' '.($key+1);?>
                                    <span style="float: right; font-weight: 100;" class="accordion_icon" id="accordion_icon_<?php echo $section['id']; ?>">
                                        <?php if($opened_section_id == $section['id']): ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </span>
                                </h6>
                                <?php echo $section['title']; ?>
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="<?php echo 'collapse-'.$section['id']; ?>" class="collapse <?php if($section_id == $section['id']) echo 'show'; ?>" aria-labelledby="<?php echo 'heading-'.$section['id']; ?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body"  style="padding:0px;">
                            <table style="width: 100%;">
                                <?php foreach ($lessons as $key => $lesson): ?>
                                    <?php
                                    if(isset($bundle_id) && $bundle_id > 0):
                                        $lesson_url = site_url('addons/course_bundles/lesson/'.rawurlencode(slugify($course_details['title'])).'/'.$bundle_id.'/'.$course_id.'/'.$lesson['id']);
                                    else:
                                        $lesson_url = site_url('home/lesson/'.slugify($course_details['title']).'/'.$course_id.'/'.$lesson['id']);
                                    endif;
                                    ?>

                                    <tr style="width: 100%; padding: 5px 0px;background-color: <?php if ($lesson_id == $lesson['id'])echo '#E6F2F5'; else echo '#fff';?>;">
                                        <td style="text-align: left; padding:7px 10px;">
                                            <?php
                                            $lesson_progress = lesson_progress($lesson['id']);
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $lesson['id']; ?>" onchange="markThisLessonAsCompleted(this.id);" value = 1 disabled <?php if($lesson_progress == 1):?> checked <?php endif; ?>>
                                                <label for="<?php echo $lesson['id']; ?>"></label>
                                            </div>

                                            <a href="<?= $lesson_url; ?>" id = "<?php echo $lesson['id']; ?>" style="color: #444549;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 400;">
                                                <?php echo $key+1; ?>:
                                                <?php if ($lesson['lesson_type'] != 'other'):?>
                                                    <?php echo $lesson['title']; ?>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php echo $lesson['title']; ?>
                                                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> -->
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </a>

                                            <div class="lesson_duration">
                                                <?php if ($lesson['lesson_type'] == 'video' || $lesson['lesson_type'] == '' || $lesson['lesson_type'] == NULL): ?>
                                                    <?php //echo $lesson['duration']; ?>
                                                    <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
                                                    <?php echo readable_time_for_humans($lesson['duration']); ?>
                                                <?php elseif($lesson['lesson_type'] == 'quiz'): ?>
                                                    <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> <?php echo get_phrase('quiz'); ?>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php if ($lesson['attachment_type'] == 'iframe'): ?>
                                                        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('external_source'); ?>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php $tmp           = explode('.', $lesson['attachment']);
                                                        $fileExtension = strtolower(end($tmp));?>
                                                        <?php if ($fileExtension == 'jpg' || $fileExtension == 'jpeg' || $fileExtension == 'png' || $fileExtension == 'bmp' || $fileExtension == 'svg'): ?>
                                                            <i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('attachment'); ?>
                                                        <?php elseif($fileExtension == 'pdf'): ?>
                                                            <i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('attachment'); ?>
                                                        <?php elseif($fileExtension == 'doc' || $fileExtension == 'docx'): ?>
                                                            <i class="far fa-file-word"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('attachment'); ?>
                                                        <?php elseif($fileExtension == 'txt'): ?>
                                                            <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('attachment'); ?>
                                                        <?php else: ?>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-file"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('attachment'); ?>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Lesson Content ends from here -->
    </div>
```

I'm developing a web application using HTML, PHP, and JavaScript. I have multiple sections, each containing lessons. I want to initially enable only the first section's lessons for user access, and then allow users to access subsequent sections after they've completed all videos in the current section.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYqVX.jpg)

Comment: A massive script dump is not necessary.  We appreciate questions containing a [mcve].  Please provide static sample input data and your exact desired textual output.  Can't you just declare a boolean (`false`) variable before looping, then when the section changes, change the boolean value (`true`)? When `false` make clickable else not.  Right?

Comment: Can't tell from your code or the screenshot, whether you are using any external video service, specific player library, or just the native `video` element. Either way, you will have to look into what client-side API whatever you are using provides, so that you can check on play state/progress. "Completing a video" probably doesn't necessarily mean "has to watch from 0:00 to {end} in one go" - the user might pause the video to grab a coffee. [...]

Comment: [...] So you will have to "sum up" individual play time intervals here. Maybe you also need to check for overlaps - me watching a 10-minute video from 0:00 to 5:00 _twice_, should probably not count as "completed the video"? And you will probably have to store the information somewhere as well - I should be able to finish watching a video when I come back tomorrow. And it should also still remember tomorrow, that I already watched the first three.